# fetch columns from a pyspark dataframe where values is equal to 0

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to fetch the columns from a dataframe where the column values is 0 but unable to do so. did anyone tried the same ever?

Comment: Do you want all the values in a particular column to be zero? Can you be more explicit or provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have a df with a single row. few of the columns are 0 and few have values greater than 0. i need to extract only those columns where value is greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

```
## Data Frame with One Row
row = [[1,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0]]
df = sc.parallelize(row).toDF(['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6','Col7','Col8','Col9','Col10'])
df.show()

#Say you have only one row hene we wrote that zero
list_of_dict = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect())[0]

zeroCol = []
for key in list_of_dict.keys():
    if list_of_dict[key] > 0:
        zeroCol.append(key)

print zeroCol

+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7|Col8|Col9|Col10|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
|   1|   0|   0|   1|   2|   3|   4|   0|   0|    0|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+

['Col6', 'Col7', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col1']
```